# how to add duplicate time to pandas dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, scikit-learn

I am loading successfully diabetes data that exists in sklearn with adding time column:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
X, y = load_diabetes(return_X_y=True)
nrows, ncols = X.shape

column_names = [str(i) for i in range(ncols)]
X = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=column_names)
# Add an arbitrary time axis
date_column_name = "Date"
dates = pd.date_range("1900-01-01", periods=nrows, freq="D")
X[date_column_name] = dates
```

Here, I am trying to add duplicate time index:

```
X[date_column_name].iloc[0:5] = list(pd.date_range('1980-01-01', freq='D', periods=1)) * 5
```

Adding duplicate time index for first 5 rows is successful but the rest is problematic and shows negative numbers.

```
print(X[date_column_name]):
1980-01-01 00:00:00
1       1980-01-01 00:00:00
2       1980-01-01 00:00:00
3       1980-01-01 00:00:00
4       1980-01-01 00:00:00
               ...         
437    -2171232000000000000
```

Is there any way how to solve this problem? Thanks.